# Custom Result Set

Tags: mysql, select

I am at a loss as how to query my database in order for it to return a result set which has dynamically generated columns from the given query. Below is the table I want to query

```
+---------+------------+-------+
| user_id |    date    |  unit |
+---------+------------+-------+
|       1 | 2014-11-08 |   2   |
|       1 | 2014-11-08 |   5   |
|       1 | 2014-11-07 |   1   |
|       2 | 2014-11-07 |   2   |
|       1 | 2014-11-08 |   1   |
|       1 | 2014-11-07 |   2   |
+---------+----------=-+-------+
```

I want to be able to select all the units entered by a specific user when the date is between 2 dates and the unit number is between 2 values. Simply for this the query would be:

```
SELECT `unit` 
FROM   `unit_table` 
WHERE  user_id = 1 
       AND (`date` BETWEEN '2014-11-05' AND '2014-11-08') 
       AND (`unit` BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
```

However I would like for the result set to be in the format below where TRUE and FALSE are 1 and 0 respectively

```
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| unit | 2014-11-05 | 2014-11-06 | 2014-11-07 | 2014-11-08 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1   |   FALSE    |   FALSE    |   TRUE     |   TRUE     |
|  2   |   FALSE    |   FALSE    |   TRUE     |   TRUE     |
|  3   |   FALSE    |   FALSE    |   FALSE    |   FALSE    |
|  4   |   FALSE    |   FALSE    |   FALSE    |   FALSE    |
|  5   |   FALSE    |   FALSE    |   FALSE    |   TRUE     |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Is this even possible or will it need to be done programatically in php from the result set?

If it is not possible any suggestions on how the database can be set up to allow this would be appreciated. Note: I want to avoid using a specific date as a column as the table has a lot of data added to it each day.

Comment: You are looking for something called `pivoting`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to Rahul for putting me onto the right track! I ended up implementing the below query which gave me what I wanted. If anyone else has a better answer feel free to answer below.

```
SELECT unit_number AS unit,
    SUM(IF(date=?,1,0)) AS day4,
    SUM(IF(date=?,1,0)) AS day3,
    SUM(IF(date=?,1,0)) AS day2,
    SUM(IF(date=?,1,0)) AS day1,
    SUM(IF(date=?,1,0)) AS day0
FROM `table_name`
WHERE user_id = 1 AND (unit BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
GROUP BY unit
```